# MVC Refreshing View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

I have a controller as below that fires of a bunch of emails:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Email Results.";

        emailQueue.emailQueueCompleted += EmailsCompleted;
        emailQueue.Run();


        List<EmailError> emails = new List<EmailError>();


        return View(emails);
    }
```

However emailQueue.Run() is an Async task that has not yet completed by the time the view is rendered. When it subsequently has completed it calls this method in the same controller below:

```
   public void EmailsCompleted(List<EmailError> errors)
    {
        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            // Do some stuff

           // Re-render view with updated errors if possible
        }
    }
```

Anyway my question is can I easily re-render the view in this controller once I get the updated list of errors back after the email queue has completed it's tasks? Alternatively should I wait for the emails to complete before even attempting to render the view initially (keep in mind this could be potentially a fairly long drawn out process). Suggestions as always are welcome as MVC is not usually an area I'm that keen to delve into.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/377394/ElmahR-equals-ELMAH-plus-SignalR that is a project using MVC and singalR which does something similar to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your architecture seems to be a bit wrong step wise. You're effectively asking "how can I do a client side update to show when the run is complete?"

You should consider changing things around; render your view first, then invoke some ajax to start sending the emails. The page then, once the emails are sent, gets the response back (remembering to sett the timeout on your ajax call to wait longer), and then can render new elements as appropriate.

**Additionally**

Typically, this sort of thing is probably best left out of a web application, and is more suited to a windows service. You can then simply render a page indicating the status of your batch sends via a page based on your DB state.